Determine the engine power
It is necessary to determine the engine power. The engine is positioned at one end of a cylinder with a mass of 300 kg, a height of 2.9 meters, and a diameter of 0.5 meters. Within 15 seconds, the cylinder needs to be moved from a horizontal to a vertical position and held in that position. The movement occurs at a constant speed. I’m completely confused about the moments of rotation—what exactly is needed, etc.
P. S. There are two schemes. They are not particularly different from each other. Am I correct in understanding that the engine must first overcome gravity and then create torque to lift the cylinder? How do I calculate these torques?

Please draw a diagram of your arrangement. Also please indicate whether this is a homework question.

power is just work per second.  Work is force times distance, force is mass time g.  So 300 * 9.8 * 2.9 / 15 = 568 watts.  Holding in the position is problematic, machines don't stop instantaneously, but let's not complicate the problem.

There are two schemes. They are not particularly different from each other. Am I correct in understanding that the engine must first overcome gravity and then create torque to lift the cylinder? How do I calculate these torques?

The case 1 is a bit easier to figure out.  Case 2 is more like what you might see in the "real world."  If we had a big cylinder on its side, you would not rotate it from the base, you'd hook onto it near the top and lift.  A consideration is when the center of gravity pasts the pivot point, you will have to stop lifting and start pushing to make sure it does not fall over on the other side.  Since the problem says you have to hold it vertical, I'll assume the pivot is in the middle of the bottom.

We do only the first scheme. They are very similar, though! The only change is the I, using parralel axis theorem: $$I_{sch 2}= I_1+ m*d^2 , \ \  300\ kg * (0.5/2)^2= 841+300/16=859.75\ kgm^2\ $$.
Also, We assume there is a mechanical latch to stop the cylinder on top; otherwise, we need four times more power to rotate it and then bring it to a stop.
The Engine, or electrical motor, does two things.
It gives the cylinder an angular acceleration to rotate it 90 degrees and lifts its CG to 1.45 m.
We calculate these two powers separately and add them.
1- Power for angular acceleration
The moment of inertia of the cylinder:
$$I=\frac{1}{3}mL^2$$

m is mass of cylinder= 300 kg
L is the length, 2.9 m

$$I=\frac{1}{3}300 kg * 2.9 m^2 = 841\ kg m^2$$
the angular acceleration,
$$\theta = 1/2\alpha t^2 \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha15 s^2$$
$$\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2}{225}= \pi/225\ rad s^2= 0.0139 \ rad \ s^2$$
Torque for rotation
$$\tau = I\alpha = 841*0.0139= 123.44 \ N.m$$
Power for angular acceleration
$$P=\tau \omega= \tau*\alpha t=123.44\ N.m *0.0139*15s=25.73\ W$$
2- Power to lift the center of gravity
The energy needed to lift the CG by 1.45/m
$$E=mgh. jouls=300*9.8*1.45= 4263\ J$$
power
$$P=\frac{E}{t}= \frac{4263}{15}=284.2\ W$$
- Total power
$$P_{total}= 25.73+284.2= 309.93$$
Check my math!
PS: Speed, both angular and linear, cannot be constant while the engine works; acceleration may be constant.
PSps, please note that we multiply the weight by G but do not multiply I of the cylinder.
